# Is the appcompatv7-28.0.0.jar deprecated?

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to add react-native-navigation (v1) to a react-native project, and this library uses appcompatv7-28.0.0.jar from google, but when I add the dependency and try to compile my project it fails because is not able to retrieve this .jar (and .pom) from the repositories where it should be:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompatv7/28.0.0/appcompatv7-28.0.0.jar

[image: Imgur]
       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompatv7/28.0.0/appcompatv7-28.0.0.jar

[image: Imgur]

I cannot find a repo to download it, has it been removed for some reason? is it deprecated and should not be used?

UPDATE:

I have tried using maven, pointing to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ but it doesn't work:

`[INFO] ---------------------------< com.javi:test >----------------------------
    [INFO] Building test 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    Downloading from Central: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.pom
    [WARNING] The POM for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:jar:28.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
    Downloading from Central: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.jar
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 5.995 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-09T12:42:44+02:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.javi:test:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.android.support:appcompat-v7:jar:28.0.0 in Central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException`

UPDATE 2:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompatv7:28.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompatv7/28.0.0/appcompatv7-28.0.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompatv7/28.0.0/appcompatv7-28.0.0.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompatv7/28.0.0/appcompatv7-28.0.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompatv7/28.0.0/appcompatv7-28.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
```

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0

Comment: Neither is it in that repository, I have updated the question.

Comment: you have to use googles repository https://maven.google.com/

Comment: In the first screenshot you can see that via browser you cannot find the artifact in maven.google.com (which redirects to https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/), and I added a second UPDATE to the question where you can see that is not finding it via console either.